# EC2 instance terminated before starting up. No console log

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created a new AMI based on an existing Fedora Core 13 AMI. When I try to launch an instance with new image, the instance gets terminated even before launching. The status of the instance changes from "pending" to "terminated." I tried to get the system log with Amazon Console, but the log is empty.

How can I find out the cause of instance termination?

**Edit**: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred due to a bug in AMI bundling utility, which in turn was caused by changes in the output of openssl in newer version. The solution is [described](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=189310) in EC2 forum. My keyword searches didn't show up this answer. I stumbled on this answer by searching for only message available for the instance. The message was

> Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown:
>   Instance initiated shutdown

The fix is a simple change in the ruby script for image bundling. The details are at the forum post linked above.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe either sounds like an issue with the AMI or a capacity issue of some sort. E.g., I noticed that I cannot start one of the high mem instances in `us-east-1b`, it had a similar effect.

As for the AWS console, I'm not aware of an error log of some sort, I'd try to start an instance from the shell using the [ec2 cli tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/368?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) and see if more errors are returned:

```
ec2-run-instances YOURAMI -n 1 -g group -k key
```

The above should return an instance identifier (`i-xxxxxx`) and *pending*.

Then use `ec2-describe-instances i-xxxxxx` to see the status of an instance. You could also try to skip `ec2-run-instances` and to use the describe command right away. Should work just as well.

Comment: Thanks, Till. Yes, this was an issue with AMI, but not related to availability zones. Please check my answer.